# Find all complex numbers satisfying the equation $\bar{z}+1=iz^2+|z|^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all complex numbers z satisfying $$\bar{z}+1=iz^2+|z|^2$$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

I only know one way i.e. assuming $z=x+iy$ but that process is very cumbersome. I don't know how to proceed otherwise with a shorter approach.

Comment: Your title is weird.

Comment: Yes, you are certainly asking a lot with that title! :)

Comment: Well, at least do it the way you know. It's not complicated at all. I don't think there is a shorter, yet equally clear way to solve this

Comment: Your title is now weirder.

Comment: It is your question, it is your responsibility to provide an informative title, not for others to figure out what a good title would be for the problem.  In this case, "equation 10" is not very informative because few people have the reference that you're looking at that has this as equation 10.

Comment: Why equation 10? Is that your homework?

Answer (score 4):

I do not find it so cumbersome to replace $z=x+iy$ if you write out the details (it looks like it might be a mess, and, without trying it out, it's hard to see where the problem simplifies).  Substituting $z=x+iy$ into the equation gives
$$
(x+1)+(-y)i=(x^2+y^2-2xy)+(x^2-y^2)i=(x-y)^2+(x^2-y^2)i.
$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
x+1&=(x-y)^2\\
-y&=x^2-y^2
\end{align*}
From here, you have that $x^2=y^2-y$.  You could, at this point, take the first equation and rewrite it as
$$
x+2xy=x^2+y^2-1.
$$
Factoring the LHS gives $x(1+2y)$ and substituting the formula for $x^2$ into the RHS gives $2y^2-y-1=(2y+1)(y-1)$.  So, this equation simplifies to:
$$
x(1+2y)=(1+2y)(y-1).
$$
Moving all the terms to one side, we get
$$
(1+2y)(y-x-1)=0.
$$
Therefore, either $1+2y=0$ or $y=1+x$.  In the first case, $y=-\frac{1}{2}$, we can find $x$ via the equation $x^2=y^2-y$, and then check our answers are right in the original expression.  If $y=1+x$, you can, again, substitute into $x^2=y^2-y$ to get a formula for $x$ (and then $y$).  Whichever of these solutions satisfies the original equation are the answers that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

setting $$z=x+iy$$ then we get (after some algebra)
$$x+1-iy=i(x^2-y^2)+(x-y)^2$$
can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is$$z=i,i\omega,i\omega^2$$where $\omega,\omega^2$ are the two complex cube roots of unity.

Putting $z=x+iy$,we get
$$(x-y)^2=1+x$$and $$x^2-y^2=-y$$
Let $A=x+y$ and also let $B=x-y$

Substituting in $$(x-y)^2=1+x$$ we get $$B^2=\frac{A+B}{2}$$i.e.$$A=2B^2-B-2$$

Substituting in $$x^2-y^2=-y$$ we get $$AB=\frac{B-A}{2}$$ i.e.$$2AB=B-A$$ Thus $$2(2B^2-B-2)B=b-2B^2+B+2$$i.e $$2B^3-3B-1=0$$ Thus $$(B+1)(2B^2-2B-1)=0$$

**Case I**$$B=-1$$
Now $$A=2B^2-B-2=1$$
$$x=\frac{A+B}{2}=0;y=\frac{A-B}{2}=1$$Thus
$$z=i$$

**Case II**$$2B^2-B-1=0$$Now $$A=2B^2-B-2$$Thus $$A+B+2-2B-1=0$$i.e$$A-B=-1$$Thus $$y=-\frac{1}{2}$$
Also $$x^2-y^2=-y$$and therefore $$x^2=\frac{3}{4}$$
$$z=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{i}{2}=i\omega,i\omega^2$$

Finally one has three solutions $$z=i,i\omega,i\omega^2$$
where $\omega,\omega^2$ are the two complex cube roots of unity.